# How to use different modalPresentationStyles based on size in swift?

Tags: swift, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

In my app, I want to present a bottom card like in the maps app. On the iPhone it should be visible on half of the screen on the iPad it should be visible as a full formSheet.

So I want to use 2 different modalPresentationStyles: .overCurrentContext and .formSheet.

Of course, when it is presented you can decide with a normal if-closure which style should be used, but I want it to adapt to traitCollection changes. How do I change the modalPresentationStyle after the UIViewController is already presented?

```
let card = CardController()
card.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
// card.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

self.present(card, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here are pictures of the expected result:
[image: Presentation on iPad]
[image: Presentation on iPhone]

The dark background behind the iPhone-card is the background of the presented ViewController, the card a UIView.

Comment: can you give screenshot of the resulting image and the expected image?

Comment: I added pictures. Hope you can help me ;-)